# Compare List<string> for containing string C#

Tags: c#, list, compare, big-o, contains

I have two lists containing strings. Each list is storing path information. `List1` contains the full UNC path to each file. `List2` contains a trimmed version of each path.

I'm trying to build a dictionary using the partial path information from `List2` as the Key and the full path info from `List1` as the value.

Example:

```
List1 = { "\\\\some\path111\to\file1.txt", "\\\\some\path222\to\file2.txt", "\\\\some\path333\to\file3.txt" };
List2 = { "\to\file3.txt", "\to\file2.txt", "\to\file1.txt" };
```

Intended result of comparison:

```
{\to\file1.txt, \\\\some\path111\to\file1.txt}
{\to\file2.txt, \\\\some\path111\to\file2.txt}
{\to\file3.txt, \\\\some\path111\to\file3.txt}
```

I managed to write something that does what I need, but it runs incredibly slow (see below). I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to speed things up or potentially store the information in a different collection to obtain quicker matches. The two lists are about 500,000 strings each.

```
private Dictionary<string, string> FullPathBuilder(List<string> partialPathList, List<string> fullPathList)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    try
    {
        foreach (string partPath in partialPathList)
        {
            foreach (string matchedFullPath in fullPathList.Where(s => s.Contains(partPath)))
            {
                if (ThirdPartyRepackVariables.cancelQC)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // get the match.  
                if (matchedFullPath != null)
                {
                    if (!result.ContainsKey(partPath))
                    {
                        result.Add(partPath, matchedFullPath);
                        ThirdPartyRepackVariables.pathsUpdated++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(partPath, partPath);
                    ThirdPartyRepackVariables.unmatchedPaths.Add(partPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error building path cross reference");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you creating these lists yourself? Are you reading them from files or smth?

Comment: Meant this to be the intended result:

{\to\file1.txt, \\some\path111\to\file1.txt}
{\to\file2.txt, \\some\path222\to\file2.txt}
{\to\file3.txt, \\some\path333\to\file3.txt}

Comment: are those items in any particular order?

Comment: Yeah the lists are being created prior. The partial paths are getting pulled from data I'm working with and the full path list is being created by crawling the directory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because probably best suited for Code Review.

Comment: I mean can you match the first item of List1 to the first item of list2?

Comment: They are not in any particular order. I'm thinking it won't always be a one-to-one match either.

Answer (score 4):

Your current implementation requires you to loop over 500,000 items (your outer foreach loop). For each one, you look at 500,000 items in the inner collection (your Where statement) to find matches.

Assuming the full path always ends with the partial (i.e. partial always includes the full file name), you could make this much faster by sorting both lists by the reverse of the path.

Having both lists sorted in the same order allows you to shortcut your loop over the second list.

Comment: It doesn't require 1-to-1. As soon as the full path is greater than the partial (ordered by reverse of the string) you can stop searching. You still get the performance gain for no match and multiple matches.

Comment: This is a good solution. If you reverse the strings in both lists, and sort them, then you can do a standard merge to find the matches.

Comment: @Abbondanza I'm not sure I understand your example. In your example, those two values would match each other, so the merge logic (greater than comparison) wouldn't come into play.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Taking [Tim Copenhaver's excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126110/1025555) to sort the input lists, I built a function that does the kind of merging you want:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> MergePaths(
    IEnumerable<string> partialPaths, IEnumerable<string> fullPaths)
{
    var sortedPartialPaths = partialPaths
        .Select(p => new { Original = p, Reverse = p.Reverse() })
        .OrderBy(p => p.Reverse)
        .ToList();

    var sortedFullPaths = fullPaths
        .Select(p => new { Original = p, Reverse = p.Reverse() })
        .OrderBy(p => p.Reverse)
        // Capture the index of each full path so we can skip full paths later.
        .Select((p, i) => new { p.Original, p.Reverse, Index = i })
        .ToList();

    var lastFullPathIndex = 0;

    return sortedPartialPaths.ToDictionary(
        pp => pp.Original,
        pp => 
        {
            var matchedFullPath = sortedFullPaths
                // Skip all full paths that have already been matched.
                .Skip(lastFullPathIndex)
                // Skip all full paths that are smaller in terms of string sort order.
                .SkipWhile(fp => fp.Reverse.CompareTo(pp.Reverse) < 0)
                // Only take the full paths that end with the matching partial path. 
                // Should only take one. If there are more the rest will be discarded.
                .TakeWhile(fp => fp.Reverse.StartsWith(pp.Reverse))
                .FirstOrDefault();

            // Update the index of our last match.
            lastFullPathIndex = matchedFullPath?.Index ?? lastFullPathIndex;

            return matchedFullPath?.Original;
        });
}
```

Be aware that it doesn't use the framework's version of `Skip()` but this `IList<T>`-specific implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Skip<T>(this IList<T> list, int count)
{
    for (var i = count; i < list.Count; i++)
        yield return list[i];
}
```

The original version turned out to be too slow, because it doesn't actually prevent superfluos enumerations for `IList<T>` types.

It also uses the following extension method to reverse the `string`s:

```
public static string Reverse(this string s)
{
    var arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}
```

### Performance

I used a simple 1:1 mapping (as descibed in [René Vogts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126042/1025555)) as a performance baseline. If we assume that every partial path can be matched to exactly one full path the following code will perform optimal, i.e. it will scale linearly with the number of paths (not counting the sorting):

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> MergePathsOneToOne(
    IList<string> partialPaths, IList<string> fullPaths)
{
    var sortedPartialPaths = partialPaths.OrderBy(p => p.Reverse()).ToList();
    var sortedFullPaths = fullPaths.OrderBy(p => p.Reverse()).ToList();

    return Enumerable
        .Range(0, sortedPartialPaths.Count)
        .ToDictionary(
            i => sortedPartialPaths[i], 
            i => sortedFullPaths[i]);
}
```

On my machine `MergePathsOneToOne()` takes about 6-7 seconds for 500,000 paths.

However, this will fail if there are partial paths that have no matching full path or if you collected full paths that are not supposed to be matched at all.

My solution performs almost as fast as the 1:1 version (7-8 seconds for 500,000 paths). But more importantly it scales the same as the 1:1 version.

See the code used for performance testing here: https://gist.github.com/bert2/de9ff3b347ac32d5cebecc4d8149a452

There you will also find two additional implementations of `MergePaths()`. One is using a `LinkedList<T>` and the other `List<T>.FindIndex(startIndex, predicate)` in order to skip full paths, but they don't perform that much better.

Please, take the performance measurments with a grain of salt. You cannot compare the absolute values, because of insufficient warm-up, GC interference and lack of smoothing. But they should give you an idea of how well each algorithm scales when you change the number of paths.

Answer (score 1):

Several things occur to me

- contains is a very slow operator, as your always matching on the end
  just check that using `EndsWith`
- unless you are expecting multiple matches (which is quite possible,
  but would break your dictionary) then you'd want to exclude matched
  results from future loops and you'd also want to break the current
  loop at the first match
- if you sort the lists before comparing then matches are more likely
  to be early in the loop

change that into code and you get

```
    //Test clocks at 137ms
    public static Dictionary<string, string> FullPathBuilderImproved(IEnumerable<string> partialPathList, IEnumerable<string> fullPathList)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        partialPathList = partialPathList.OrderBy(s => string.Concat(s.Reverse()));
        List<string> unmatchedList = fullPathList.OrderBy(s =>string.Concat(s.Reverse())).ToList();

        foreach (string partPath in partialPathList)
        {
            string matchedFullPath = unmatchedList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.EndsWith(partPath));
            if (matchedFullPath != null)
            {
                result.Add(partPath, matchedFullPath);
                unmatchedList.Remove(matchedFullPath);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(partPath, partPath);

            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

where as your code Clocked in at 20 seconds

both tests uses this code to generate test data

```
    IEnumerable<string> partial = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(i => System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()).ToList();
    IEnumerable<string> full = partial.Select(i => System.IO.Path.Combine( System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(),i)).ToList();
```

EDIT: in review i think Abbondanza reverse function would be quicker than the Reverse concatenate i used

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way would be something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = List2.ToDictionary(s => s, 
                       s => List1.FirstOrDefault(f => f.EndsWith(s)) ?? s);
```

But I'm not good at determining exactly how the execution time behaves. It iterates one time through the list of trimmed paths. But for each trimmed path the list of full paths is scanned for the matching element. So I guess it's something like O(n*logn) (though I don't even know if this notation is correct).

To update those other two properties of `ThirdPartyRepackVariables` you can change the code like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = List2.ToDictionary(s => s, 
                       s =>
                       {
                           string v =  List1.FirstOrDefault(f => f.EndsWith(s));
                           if (v == null)
                           {
                               ThirdPartyRepackVariables.unmatchedPaths.Add(s);
                               return s;
                           }
                           ThirdPartyRepackVariables.pathsUpdated++;
                           return v;
                       });
```

---

If you have one-to-one matches (so for every trimmed path there is one full path and the other way too) you could at first sort your lists as [Tim Copenhaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126110/5528593) suggested:

```
var sortedList1 = list1.OrderBy(s => new string(s.Reverse().ToArray())).ToList();
var sortedList2 = list2.OrderBy(s => new string(s.Reverse().ToArray())).ToList();
```

and then simply turn them into a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = Enumerable.Range(0, sortedList1.Count)
                       .ToDictionary(i => sortedList2[i], i => sortedList1[i]);
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks! How would I return the two values to add to the dictionary collection?

Comment: @complhex I don't understand, the dictionary is created by `ToDictionary`, the first lambda returns the key (the trimmed path) and the second returns the value (the matching full path or the trimmed path again).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Just getting used to LINQ/Lambda - stuff always confuses me

Comment: @complhex added a version that also updates your `ThirdPartyRepackVariables` properties.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with the [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) string matching algorithm. I have an implementation at https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=869.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
// build the automaton
var matcher = new AhoCorasickStringSearcher();
foreach (var partial in partialList)
{
    matcher.AddItem(partial);
}
matcher.CreateFailureFunction();

// now search each line . . .
foreach (var line in fullPaths)
{
    var matches = matcher.Search(line);
    // here, if matches contains items, you can add them to your dictionary
}
```

This should execute very quickly.

You'll need to read the article for more detail about how to use it, but that's the gist of it.

That said, the suggestion to reverse the strings and sort, and then run a standard merge algorithm is a good one. It's easy to implement, and quite possibly faster.

Comment: The link just takes me to informit.com startpage. Cant find the guide

Comment: @mattias: Unfortunately, the Guide no longer exists.